# Redirecting my site to https://www.msn.com/en-in/ while logout

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory authentication. The Login is successful for authenticated users but the logout does not return to the original site/login page but instead redirects to **https://www.msn.com/en-in**.

On Azure Active Directory I have set reply url, logout url etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that your Logout URL matches what you have in your Account controller? Your Account controller needs to have a Signout and EndSession method. The code in my controller looks like this:

public void SignOut()

```
{

    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.

    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(

        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

}



public void EndSession()

{

    // If AAD sends a single sign-out message to the app, end the user's session, but don't redirect to AAD for sign out.

    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

}
```

Then your logout URL in the app registration needs to match whats in your Account controller. In the example here it would be: https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/EndSession